# Google Script MergedRanges performance issue

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to breakApart merged cells that are empty. The following code works but is so slow it often times out when working with for example 200+ merged ranges, any suggestions on how to improve performance?

```
function EmptyMerged() {

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("1");

var range = sheet.getRange("B3:NA27");


var mergedRanges = range.getMergedRanges();
for (var i = 0; i < mergedRanges.length ; i++) {


  if(mergedRanges[i].isBlank() === true){
            mergedRanges[i].breakApart();
  }
}};
```

Comment: What is the end goal of this? I am asking because you could do batch executions. Run the script though a 5 minute or an hour trigger and make the script only do a few at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, I would like to propose to use RangeList for reducing the process cost of your script. When your script is modified, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
function EmptyMerged() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("1");
  var range = sheet.getRange("B3:NA27");
  var mergedRanges = range.getMergedRanges();
  
  // I modified below script.
  var ranges = mergedRanges.reduce((ar, r) => {
    if (r.isBlank()) ar.push(r.getA1Notation());
    return ar;
  }, []);
  sheet.getRangeList(ranges).breakApart();
}
```

#### Note:

- I think that in your situation, Sheets API can be also used. But I thought that when the range list is used, the script will be simpler. So I proposed above modified script. If above modified script was not the direct solution of your issue, please tell me. At that time, I would like to propose to use Sheets API.

#### References:

- [Class RangeList](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range-list)
- [breakApart() of Class RangeList](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range-list#breakApart())

### Added 1:

From your following replying,

> Thanks for the help! This does indeed seem to be a bit faster, but unfortunately the script is still taking too long to execute (Timed Out). I'm new to Sheets API, so any further explanation would be much appreciated.

I add the sample script for achieving your goal using Sheets API.

#### Sample script:

Before you use this script, [please enable Sheets API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services).

```
function EmptyMerged2() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("1");
  var range = sheet.getRange("B3:NA27");
  var startRowIndex = range.getRow() - 1;
  var startColumnIndex = range.getColumn() - 1;
  var endRowIndex = startRowIndex + range.getNumRows();
  var endColumnIndex = startColumnIndex + range.getNumColumns();
  var requests = [{unmergeCells: {range: {sheetId: sheet.getSheetId(), startRowIndex: startRowIndex, startColumnIndex: startColumnIndex, endRowIndex: endRowIndex, endColumnIndex: endColumnIndex}}}];
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({requests: requests}, ss.getId());
}
```

If you want to unmerge all merged cells in a sheet, you can also use the following script. It becomes a bit simpler.

```
function EmptyMerged3() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("1");
  var requests = [{unmergeCells: {range: {sheetId: sheet.getSheetId()}}}];
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({requests: requests}, ss.getId());
}
```

#### Reference:

- [Method: spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)

### Added 2:

The following sample script unmerges the merged cells which are empty.

#### Sample script:

```
function EmptyMerged4() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("1");
  var range = sheet.getRange("B3:NA27");
  var mergedRanges = range.getMergedRanges();
  var sheetId = sheet.getSheetId();
  var requests = mergedRanges.reduce((ar, e) => {
    if (e.isBlank()) {
      var startRowIndex = e.getRow() - 1;
      var startColumnIndex = e.getColumn() - 1;
      var endRowIndex = startRowIndex + e.getNumRows();
      var endColumnIndex = startColumnIndex + e.getNumColumns();
      ar.push({unmergeCells: {range: {sheetId: sheetId, startRowIndex: startRowIndex, startColumnIndex: startColumnIndex, endRowIndex: endRowIndex, endColumnIndex: endColumnIndex}}});
    }
    return ar;
  }, []);
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({requests: requests}, ss.getId());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! This does indeed seem to be a bit faster, but unfortunately the script is still taking too long to execute (Timed Out). I'm new to Sheets API, so any further explanation would be much appreciated.

Comment: @JellevhS Thank you for replying. I deeply apologize for the inconvenience. From your replying, I added the sample script using Sheets API. Could you please confirm it? If that didn't resolve your issue, I apologize again.

Comment: first of all, no need to apologize whatsoever, I'm more than thrilled anyone's actually taking their time to help me out! The script works great (and is extremely fast!), but it seems to be unmerging all merged cells instead of just the empty merged cells. Is there any way to add some sort of condition to this script, so that it will only unmerge cells when they are empty? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @JellevhS Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for the inconvenience. I forgot about it. So I added one more sample script. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your goal, I apologize again.

Comment: This script works exactly as intended. Thanks a lot!